# outer join with not in and for each in sql

Tags: sql

This one has only one table with three columns student, lect and score. for each lecture I need to find the students who have not got any score.

I have written the below query which uses outer joins, but it can do so only for one lect at a time.

Eg: see below I passed 'L02'

How do I get this working for all the lect values as in (L01,L02,L03...etc)

```
select distinct * from 
(
select  distinct Student from import1
where lect ='L02'
)i1 
right outer join
(select  distinct Student from import1) i2
on i1.Student=i2.Student 
where i1.Student is null
```

output of above is

[image: output of query]

This works for L02. But, how do I modify above to include for all lect values without hardcoding the values of lect?

Sample data from table:

[image: sample data]

Comment: how is no score defined here? will the score col be empty or have a null value?

Comment: ok...sorry I should have added that information.. a student with no score means that his name would be missing in the table for that particular lecture.So we ,should be looking for a student whose name doesnot appear in L01. SO,say student 'A' has not got a score for L01 then his entry would not be there for L01.So we are looking at students who have not been scored for these lectures.

Comment: This is not possible if u hv just one table. U need a separate students table to keep track of the overall students. THen outer join on the full tbale of students and the lectures table and filter for those that arent in lectures table.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.......I am able to do it for just one  lecture at a time..But not for all ...

Comment: Right now, ur join is giving u results of students who have attended other lectures except lec2. Consider a student who hasnt attended any lectures... they wont turn up in ur query results.

Comment: No ,it gives me the students not scored for L02.

Comment: This also gives me the same result,but only for L02    select  distinct Student from import1 
where student not in (select distinct Student from import1
where lect ='L02')

Comment: In the join query i am using NULL to find the students not being scored.

Comment: Yes. We are saying the same things. Consider a student who has not been scored for all lectures. Right now, they wont be listed since they wont be in the table for any lecture.

Comment: I agree on that. But can we make this work for all lectures ,using some modifications to my query ? if possible .Thanks

Comment: I dont think it is possible, atleast I cant think of a way. If u get a solution, pls post it. I would love to see a way to achieve this.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

Need a dataset of all possible student/lecture pairs. If the one table contains all the students and lectures that need to be considered, this dataset can be built with:
`SELECT Student, Lect FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Student FROM import1) AS S, (SELECT DISTINCT Lect FROM import1) AS L`

Otherwise, need a table of all students and a table of all lectures then query:
`SELECT Student, Lect FROM Students, Lectures`

Now join that query to the scores table with compound link on both identifier fields and use appropriate filter criteria.

```
SELECT Query1.Student, Query1.Lect, import1.Score
FROM Query1 LEFT JOIN import1 
ON (Query1.Lect = import1.Lect) AND (Query1.Student = import1.Student)
WHERE Score Is Null;
```

Tested with an Access database.